# Using System.Xml.Xpath.XPathSelectElement where the xpath contains a where clause

Tags: c#, xpath, .net-4.0

My question is, does the XPathSelectElement method support a where clause in the xpath query?

Here is an example of what I am trying to do:

```
var element = coreXml.XPathSelectElement(configuration/system.serviceModel/client/endpoint[@name='SomeService']);
```

When I run this I am returned 'null' based on the follow xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <client>
            <endpoint address="http://localhost:40901/SomeService/" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="SomeContract" name="SomeService"/>
        </client>
    </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't reproduce the problem, I saved your XML samples as "XMLFile2.xml" in a C# console project, then corrected your code sample to wrap the XPath expression  passed to XPathSelectElement in double quotes and made the following code sample:

```
    XDocument coreXml = XDocument.Load("../../XMLFile2.xml");
    var element = coreXml.XPathSelectElement("configuration/system.serviceModel/client/endpoint[@name='SomeService']");
    Console.WriteLine(element == null);
```

It outputs "False".

So something in your real code is different.

Comment: Yes, you are correct, there is nothing wrong with the example, but my setup populated the xpath query in the XPathSelectElement() method to a section of the xml that did not in fact exist. So, the problem I had was that I was using an xpath query from a separate file which contained a mistake. For my example I rewrote the query from hand, hence your example worked.

Comment: To answer my question, yes the method can accept a query similar to the one I had.